# Unable to upload image with codeigniter

Tags: image, file, codeigniter, upload

I have trying to post some values to table with an image but when i try to upload file name saved in table but image doesn't move to directory. i have checked directory permission. 
but still no luck.

function:

```
  function add_multiple_choice_question($quiz_id)  {
if (sizeof($this->input->post('options')) != $this->input->post('number_of_options')) {
  return false;
}
foreach ($this->input->post('options') as $option) {
  if ($option == "") {
    return false;
  }
}
if (sizeof($this->input->post('correct_answers')) == 0) {
  $correct_answers = [""];
} else {
  $correct_answers = $this->input->post('correct_answers');
}
$data['quiz_id']            = $quiz_id;
$data['title']              = html_escape($this->input->post('title'));
$data['number_of_options']  = html_escape($this->input->post('number_of_options'));
$data['type']               = 'multiple_choice';
$data['options']            = json_encode($this->input->post('options'));
$data['correct_answers']    = json_encode($correct_answers);    

   if (!file_exists('uploads/quiz_image')) {
    mkdir('uploads/quiz_image', 0777, true);
  }
  if ($_FILES['quiz_image']['name'] == "") {
    $data['quiz_image'] = 'category-thumbnail.png';
  } else {
    $data['quiz_image'] = md5(rand(10000000, 20000000)) . '.jpg';
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['quiz_image']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/quiz_image/' . $data['quiz_image']);
  }
$this->db->insert('question', $data);
return true;  }
```

Unable to move file to directory

Form

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('admin/quiz_questions/'.$param2.'/add'); ?>"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id = 'mcq_form'>
<input type="hidden" name="question_type" value="mcq">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title"><?php echo get_phrase('question_title'); ?></label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" id="title" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title"><?php echo get_phrase('quiz_image'); ?></label>
    <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="custom-file">
                                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="quiz_image" onchange="changeTitleOfImageUploader(this)" accept="image/*">
                                    <label class="custom-file-label ellipsis" for=""><?php echo get_phrase('choose_file'); ?></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id='multiple_choice_question'>
    <label for="number_of_options"><?php echo get_phrase('number_of_options'); ?></label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="number_of_options" id="number_of_options" data-validate="required" data-message-required="Value Required" min="0">
        <div class="input-group-append" style="padding: 0px"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm pull-right" name="button" onclick="showOptions(jQuery('#number_of_options').val())" style="border-radius: 0px;"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
    <button class = "btn btn-success" id = "submitButton" type="button" name="button" data-dismiss="modal"><?php echo get_phrase('submit'); ?></button>
</div>
```

application is using script but i am not experienced with it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showOptions(number_of_options){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/manage_multiple_choices_options'); ?>",
        data: {number_of_options : number_of_options},
        success: function(response){
            jQuery('.options').remove();
            jQuery('#multiple_choice_question').after(response);
        }
    });
}

$('#submitButton').click( function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/quiz_questions/'.$param2.'/add'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('form#mcq_form').serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
           if (response == 1) {
               success_notify('<?php echo get_phrase('question_has_been_added'); ?>');
           }else {
               error_notify('<?php echo get_phrase('no_options_can_be_blank_and_there_has_to_be_atleast_one_answer'); ?>');
           }
         }
    });
    showLargeModal('<?php echo site_url('modal/popup/quiz_questions/'.$param2); ?>', '<?php echo get_phrase('manage_quiz_questions'); ?>');
});
</script>
```

Controller

```
  public function quiz_questions($quiz_id = "", $action = "", $question_id = "") {
if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != true) {
  redirect(site_url('login'), 'refresh');
}
$quiz_details = $this->crud_model->get_lessons('lesson', $quiz_id)->row_array();

if ($action == 'add') {
  $response = $this->crud_model->add_quiz_questions($quiz_id);
  echo $response;
}

elseif ($action == 'edit') {
  $response = $this->crud_model->update_quiz_questions($question_id);
  echo $response;
}

elseif ($action == 'delete') {
  $response = $this->crud_model->delete_quiz_question($question_id);
  $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('question_has_been_deleted'));
  redirect(site_url('admin/course_form/course_edit/'.$quiz_details['course_id']));
}
}
```

i searched too much n tried all trick but no luck.

Comment: Why don't you use [File Uploading Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html) ?

Comment: how's your form?